# Fastest way to add two big numbers (a million digits)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Constraint:

1 ≤  ≤  ≤ 10^1000000

Input:

```
1000211 1000299
```

Output:

```
2000510
```

The runtime must be <4 s.

I've already tried but it's still too slow:

```
x, y = input().split()
print(int(x) + int(y))
```

Comment: I'm curious, I got the answer in nano sec. How did you get second?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew You must've tried only tiny numbers, nowhere near the size limit.

Comment: @KellyBundy I mean, even if I sum `10^1000000` it is taking like `0.00013` seconds. `print`ing, on the other hand. will be slow.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nah, I'd say it's not the printing (depends on what exactly we mean by that).

Comment: @KellyBundy I mean, it took almost 10 seconds on my machine to print the result (a 2016 mbp). I mean the time it takes to `print(result)` where `result = int(x) + int(y)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But are you talking about the actual printing, as in, writing the characters to some output, or do you include the conversion from int to string? I consider it the former, as I find the distinction valuable here.

Comment: If it takes you more than 4 seconds to sum those two numbers you are doing something seriously wrong.

Comment: @StephenQuan Looks like you overlooked the limit as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, e.g. `timeit("print(z)",setup="x = y = 10**1000000; z = x + y", number=1)`

Comment: @KellyBundy again, the actual summing of even numbers at the limit only takes microseconds.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The actual printing of the string also only takes microseconds (or maybe like 2 milliseconds).

Comment: Printing can be slow or fast depending on things like whether you're outputting to a file or a terminal that caches N lines and does line-wrapping. (Printing in IDLE is extremely slow, for example.) But it's definitely the conversion from base 2 to base 10 (and, presumably, from base 10 to base 2 in the first place) that is the bottleneck here.

Comment: I'm getting a decimal overflow error, though, if I try to sum two of the max numbers!

Comment: @kaya3 The site where they're doing this is most certainly not using some person running everyone's submissions in an IDLE shell :-). Probably writing to a file. And most certainly it takes much less time than the conversion. But yes, the fact that printing itself *can* be slow is one of the reasons I find the distinction valuable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you mean when you use `decimal.Decimal`? Or with `int`?

Comment: @KellyBundy with `decimal.Decimal`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then you forgot to configure it for bignum as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You're converting from decimal to binary and back. At least in CPython, that takes quadratic time (or causes an error). Instead of `int`, use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal), after configuring for "bignum arithmetic" as shown near the end of that page. Then it takes linear time.

Timings of the steps with both numbers at the limit:

```
int() 14.1069 seconds
add    0.0005 seconds
str() 15.9351 seconds
print  0.0019 seconds
```

And with using `Decimal` as `int`:

```
int()  0.0366 seconds
add    0.0001 seconds
str()  0.0043 seconds
print  0.0009 seconds
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLTsMwELz7K1bi4BgCPYAErdQDKkXqoRUCDtyQk2waq04c2RuaCvHtxXYCVFjyY3Zmd8dO2gNVprm@a@3xWFpTA6kaQdWtsRTPLEZz0xD2pFX2w1kslMWc3h0VpiM2hpVh7Axe0CcbeLUdQmksdE41W3jAXNVSg3SgGoJEQiXzXRCaD7R7q8h3JtBqh0CVpBSyjqDGKoV9ZSCXFh1UaFEwVcKj1A5nDPyIFoux@mjkPDIOabSeLMa99a7n6/u396fn5SKFZS37CJd@CVA18/Vq4@FqI0QsEszOf9wzVmDpbx@aJFpmqMVgYqtN5ttTBK31SQOdQsk/w0smAi6BZrdXN@WXN@Z9FY4PHUL9QcJY788HP/mUn0/jYCd0n0YyVO9FGveDYKMdHqDwNZ2X9HABh19GFgXAyDiyiftLCjAk7RVVYFpsEj4p8GPSdFrzFPiei/DJfChEhstG7b9fIBkVUV0Our@3OGkYA1wcj98)):

```
from time import time
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

# Set to True for using Decimal as int (a hack to overwrite it like that, but meh, who cares here)
if False:
    from decimal import *
    setcontext(Context(prec=MAX_PREC, Emax=MAX_EMAX, Emin=MIN_EMIN))
    int = Decimal

def report(label):
    global t
    print(label, f'{time() - t:7.4f} seconds')
    t = time()

x = y = '9'*999999
t = time()
x, y = int(x), int(y)
report('int()')
s = x + y
report('add  ')
s = str(s)
report('str()')
with open('/dev/null', 'w') as devnull:
    with redirect_stdout(devnull) as f:
        print(s)
report('print')
```

Comment: Does `Decimal` really use a decimal internal representation allowing linear time arithmetic? Seems like it uses `int` internally with a mantissa and a (base-10) exponent. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/_pydecimal.py#L1233

Comment: wait, why does it take quadratic time?

Comment: @kaya3 the actual implementation is in C. But good catch! `int` takes about 5 seconds compared to 0.005 seconds for conversion to `Decimal`

Comment: @kaya3 Not quite decimal, but a power of 10 as base. And yes, it's linear. You're looking at the Python implementation, which isn't used. The C implementation is.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because it uses naive algorithms.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any way of converting between two bases in linear time, unless both bases are powers of the same thing (e.g. hexadecimal to binary or octal can be done in linear time).

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, for "compatible" bases like hex-to-oct, it's linear, and for "incompatible" bases, best known is O(n log² n).

Comment: Supplement: In the latest repair versions (Python 3.10.7, Python 3.9.14, Python 3.8.14, Python 3.7.14), the `int` solution will rasie errors, because CPython will limit the length of the string to be parsed to less than 4300 (but this is configurable).

Comment: @MechanicPig Correct, that's the error I meant. Didn't want to distract with details but also couldn't not mention it.

Answer (score 3):

[Edit: Including feedback from Kelly]

Here's the old-school way of doing big integer addition.

- You start at the back of the string, i.e. units, then move up, i.e. tens, etc
- You do 1 digit addition and you keep a running carry bit

Representing this in Python it would be easy to reverse the string with `[::-1]` so that you can start at index 0 of the string for the units, index 1 of the string for tens, and so forth. We do all digits until we run out and the carry has diminished to 0.

As per Kelly's advice, we stage the result in a string array and, when we're done, we turn it back into a string with a join.

Also, as pointed out by Kelly this may not be the fastest way since the algorithm is not in native code. When I ran this on tio.run I hit the 4s threshold close to 10^1000000. So the algorithm just scrapes in, satisfying the criteria.

```py
import re

def sum(a, b):
    a = [int(e) for e in re.findall('.', a)][::-1]
    b = [int(e) for e in re.findall('.', b)][::-1]
    carry = 0
    i = 0
    result = [ ]
    while (i < len(a) or i < len(b) or carry > 0):
        sum = (a[i] if i < len(a) else 0) + (b[i] if i < len(b) else 0) + carry
        result.append(sum % 10)
        carry = sum // 10
        i = i + 1
    return "".join([str(e) for e in result[::-1]])

while True:
    print("Input:")
    a, b = input().split()
    print("Output:", sum(a, b))
```

To improve performance, rather than add 1 digit at a time, we can consider adding 8 digits at a time. The new algorithm:

- Pads the number to an exact multiple of 8 characters
- Then uses regular expressions to split this into an array of 8 characters
- Convert the array of 8 characters into an array of 8-digit numbers
- Then the while loop does 8-digit number addition with carry
- When we have our result, we convert it back into an array of 8 characters and clean it up

```py
import re

def sum(a, b):
    if (len(a) % 8) > 0: a = a.zfill(len(a) + 8 - (len(a) % 8))
    if (len(b) % 8) > 0: b = b.zfill(len(b) + 8 - (len(b) % 8))
    a = re.findall('........', a)
    b = re.findall('........', b)
    a = [int(e) for e in a][::-1]
    b = [int(e) for e in b][::-1]
    carry = 0
    i = 0
    result = [ ]
    while (i < len(a) or i < len(b) or carry > 0):
        sum = (a[i] if i < len(a) else 0) + (b[i] if i < len(b) else 0) + carry
        result.append(sum % 100000000)
        carry = sum // 100000000
        i = i + 1
    return "".join([str(e).zfill(8) for e in result[::-1]]).lstrip("0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark answer, comparing the different solutions with two numbers at the limit (using strings for input/output):

```
28.246 seconds  sum_with_int
 0.035 seconds  sum_with_Decimal
 3.574 seconds  sum_by_hand
 0.479 seconds  sum_by_hand_8
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VTfb9owEH7PX3FCQrHbNAUhTRSNSVPHQx9aTX2ahFBkgzM8JSZyjFr2z7M7O2RJGfvxunsIPs7fd767z64Obrszk2llj0ddVjvrwKoo2qgc6n2ZvWi3zbRxTCQg@SwCNKvc3hqonWU@wuEaaCE5fwP8pNa6FMUFcBslgpPTI5GHbCvMposXMIclZVMc8p0FhamRNM212YiiYHEaJyD4ajmb3YxXHiL/BiJ7kLWw9oCwkfd0u7Kq3heO@CBsfNnqQgHT8B4KZagUTHDypPcC1wcYNRWQYXFIwsRSr0Dn0IGrola4FTvC5Juo7EY9a8sXzpWKqlLYLmIfwnjE2/ipHorc3mKojVBtGvnG3ekMBum3nTZsSWPqd43yhEatzgeVTbujwqOzpqohTDm1YObnJ9LvucbGN8FrmMJNbyvv4WUXT8OUHbzs4WUXT6l6Y27MC6RVxoUdkl@Wm/ijuuT/J6bGfqOpxv5JWs0kpxc1lha4UVdsMBqg3vK9WdchZ/s0JWfvTdLVZNIXKHLYXQlOl5gsvHe0Dv9uAv4UuIqiWrn1zjj16th981tZtZ4/fvySfX5e3CewKMWrdxf4IVeb@ePDE7oPT/SWkYJII/FdDFcwGUVUaE6F@mLCGCtLCsrD7TkD3XnzwMx3SJivio0bCfyKj4yURaWxnyNrErR@SBsP36UTvMcKK93UEOO4WQDitXI8gTzNMiNKlWW8c1p@PP4A)):

Old link ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLfS8MwEH7vX3EIsmSrc2MgOpwgugcfFPFJGBLSNnWRNi1phu6vn3dJWyvTQNvcXb/vfnxX7922MovL2h4Omcqh2ZXiU7ut0MYxGUPClxHgscrtrIHGWeYjHCZAl4TzKPoFvFepLmXxD7iPEkFn/CJJ9mIrTTbESwErkJvl8mz@5h0JOZKBw6pmVzh0biA4NN5n/pZKa/e99bnVhQKm4RoKZZgUHCoLnZkEM0BuYNbm9zVk@l1TBt@@2Og3DjqHIZEqGtWm8UUOEckRIjlGYPvUaMBNOoJJqKf/K/Q6lXWtcEw0VMKdwnyGY@x@6rqm0Pk5xvoITUYj6XwozcnJ9KPShgVu3k42yncmbQJLvxXxkdTxUDcE2aoEp0sFuqwr6/w9eLMA6ALjKGqUSyvj1Jdjd@23tipdPd6@iueX9V0M61J@eXONLzK1WT0@PKH58ER7I2kV8BldjWAMi1mUo4I4ZgO@@qBgbUmEPCzVEejKHw8UBLTSvCs2b9X/i48OSUutsZ@ptwl6O6QdnV5MF7jcCjvNGhihViwA4QwcjyGfCmFkqYTgg2r54fAN)):

```
def sum_with_int(a, b):
    return str(int(a) + int(b))

def sum_with_Decimal(a, b):
    return str(Decimal(a) + Decimal(b))

def sum_by_hand(a, b):
    a = [int(e) for e in re.findall('.', a)][::-1]
    b = [int(e) for e in re.findall('.', b)][::-1]
    carry = 0
    i = 0
    result = [ ]
    while (i < len(a) or i < len(b) or carry > 0):
        sum = (a[i] if i < len(a) else 0) + (b[i] if i < len(b) else 0) + carry
        result.append(sum % 10)
        carry = sum // 10
        i = i + 1
    return "".join([str(e) for e in result[::-1]])

def sum_by_hand_8(a, b):
    if (len(a) % 8) > 0: a = a.zfill(len(a) + 8 - (len(a) % 8))
    if (len(b) % 8) > 0: b = b.zfill(len(b) + 8 - (len(b) % 8))
    a = re.findall('........', a)
    b = re.findall('........', b)
    a = [int(e) for e in a][::-1]
    b = [int(e) for e in b][::-1]
    carry = 0
    i = 0
    result = [ ]
    while (i < len(a) or i < len(b) or carry > 0):
        sum = (a[i] if i < len(a) else 0) + (b[i] if i < len(b) else 0) + carry
        result.append(sum % 100000000)
        carry = sum // 100000000
        i = i + 1
    return "".join([str(e).zfill(8) for e in result[::-1]]).lstrip("0")

funcs = sum_with_int, sum_with_Decimal, sum_by_hand, sum_by_hand_8

from time import time
from decimal import *

setcontext(Context(prec=MAX_PREC, Emax=MAX_EMAX, Emin=MIN_EMIN))

a = b = '9' * 30
for f in funcs:
    print(f(a, b))

a = b = '9' * 999999
for _ in range(1):
    for f in funcs:
        t = time()
        f(a, b)
        print('%6.3f seconds ' % (time() - t), f.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Hmm, why vote "not useful" for a benchmark for a question asking for the "fastest way"?